# Is it true that all proper normal subgroups of $D_{24}$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that all proper normal subgroups of $D_{24}$ abelian ? If Yes, is it true only for $D_{4n}$ groups, or for all $D_{2n}$.

I was trying to list all proper normal subgroups of $D_{24}$, Using the fact that $Z(D_{24})=\{1,r^6\}$ this is what I have by now :

$$<r>,<r^2>,<r^3>,<r^4>,<r^6>,<r^6,s>,<r^6,r^3s>$$

and all above normal subgroups are abelian. Are there any other normal groups in $D_{24}$ ? Thanks !

Comment: No, $D_{12}$ is a nonabelian normal subgroup of $D_{24}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative for $D_{24}$.
Let's consider more general cases. If $n$ is odd, all proper normal subgroups are $<r^d>$, where $d|n$. Hence, they are all abelian. But if $n$ is even, there are two more proper normal subgroups: $<r^2, s>$ and $<r^2, rs>$, which are not abelian.
The proof of assertions above can be easily completed by considering conjugate classes of $D_{2n}$. Read [this](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091014113730AA7KJDt) for details.